# How to insert object into rails model at a certain index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a resource in rails, `Image`. There are a fixed amount of image objects (3 in this case) in the model. The user doesn't "upload more pictures", but instead "sets/updates one of the current pictures" in the model. So when a picture is uploaded, one must be deleted to put that image in.

```
def create 
    image = Image.find(image_params["index"])
    image.destroy

end
```

When uploading an image, the user must specify which image they want to "set". The image in that position is deleted. Now I need to upload the new image in that specific row in the table. Is this possible, and if so, how would I implement this?

I'm also very open to advice on a better way of doing this. This entire process doesn't seem proper to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I assume you're new to rails, so lets keep things simple:

1 - Add 3 image ids to your user migration / database:

```
add_column :users, :image_1_id, :integer
add_column :users, :image_2_id, :integer
add_column :users, :image_3_id, :integer
```

2 - Make sure your user has the 3 images relations

```
class User
  belongs_to :image_1, class_name: "Image"
  belongs_to :image_2, class_name: "Image"
  belongs_to :image_3, class_name: "Image"
end
```

3 - Refer to them in your views, and update them in your controllers. No need to remove them if they exist, just update them.

Comment: You're right, I'm very new. Few questions: What exactly are you doing in step 1? I don't have a User, it's the home page of an ecommerce website and an admin (through http validation) needs to be able to update these pictures on the home page. Do I still need to do anything like you've done in step 2?

Comment: Instead of user, you could for example have a model named Page. That means that you could store images against your Page model.